# Output the results of an RE

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
import re

targetFile = open("test.txt").read()

print(re.search('(<\\/nesting_tag>)',targetFile))
```

The idea is I return everything between the . E.g. "Test" when Test. How can I return "Test" as opposed to <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(56, 70), match=''>?

Comment: Give a proper example input please.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
print(re.search('(<\\/nesting_tag>)',targetFile).group())
```